# How to take screenshot of googlemap from web page using PhantomJs?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, phantomjs

My Requirement is to take screen shot of Google Map of web page.I am drawing  Markers and Polyline dynamically on Google Map.I am using PhantomJS for taking screen shot.But screen shot is not capturing of complete Google Map which is displaying on web page.

```
Html and javascript for loading and display google map
----------
     <script>
            function initMap() {
                    var mapOptions = {
                        zoom: 15,
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng(28.5354383, 77.26393259999998)
                    };
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
                    var project_id = $('#project').data('url')
                    var latt = substation[0]
                    var lngg = substation[1]
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(latt, lngg),
                        title: new google.maps.LatLng(latt, lngg).toUrlValue(6),
                        map: map,
                        draggable: true,
                        label: {
                            color: 'black',
                            fontWeight: 'bold',
                            text: "Sub-Station",
                        },
                        icon: {
                            labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(4, 25),
                            url: '/assets/sub_station.png',
                        }
                    });
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "dragend", function(event) {
                        $.getScript("/update_pole.js?project_id=" + project_id + "&Type=SS" + "&new_cordinated=" + event.latLng.toString().slice(1, -1), function(data) {});
                    });
                    var lattt = feeder[0]
                    var lnggg = feeder[1]
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lattt, lnggg),
                        title: new google.maps.LatLng(lattt, lnggg).toUrlValue(6),
                        map: map,
                        draggable: true,
                        label: {
                            color: 'black',
                            fontWeight: 'bold',
                            text: "Feeder",
                        },
                        icon: {
                            labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(4, 25),
                            url: '/assets/ptw.png',
                        }
                    });
```

### PhantomJs for capture screenshot

```js
var page = require('webpage').create();
  page.open('https://medhajtest.herokuapp.com/admin/visibilities/demo?id=586b524712598e0004f440d0', function() {
  page.viewportSize = { width: 1440, height: 900 };
  var clipRect = page.evaluate(function(){
    return document.querySelector("div#map").getBoundingClientRect();
  });
  page.render('github.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

### Expected Screen Shot

[image]

### Currently Coming Screen Shot

[image]

Comment: it looks like you are expecting google maps with zoomed out view, right?

Comment: No,I  want to take screen screen shot of all that portion of google map where marker and polyline is draw on map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the dimensions of your screenshot, 400x300. It's the default PhantomJS viewport size. You must set the desired viewport size before opening a page.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

// Got to set this before opening a page
page.viewportSize = { width: 1440, height: 900 };

page.open('https://medhajtest.herokuapp.com/admin/visibilities/demo?id=586b524712598e0004f440d0', function() {
    var clipRect = page.evaluate(function(){
        return document.querySelector("div#map").getBoundingClientRect();
    });
    page.render('github.png');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: Hello Vaviloff now i am facing another hurdlei want to capture the screenshot of a page in the active admin but when i am trying this it's asking for login ? is it possible to take screen shot without login?
can you please help me out?

Comment: Is it possible to view the admin area in your normal browser without logging in? No, of course not. You should search on how to log in to sites with PhantomJS.